# how to tell which libxml2 functions returning objects that need to be free?

Tags: c, libxml2

Are there references somewhere on whether an object returned from a certain function need to be freed?  Currently, I just try ...Free() on objects returned by functions with words such as "new", "copy", "create", in their names and if the program does not crash, I assume the call is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very bad idea. If you're working with a library API that returns pointers to allocated objects, *especially* if the objects allocated are of an "opaque" type where you don't directly access them but only pass them to other functions, then the library almost certainly provides its own functions to close/release/destruct/free these objects. There are multiple reasons you should not just use `free`:

1. The object created by the library is unlikely to be a single allocation obtained by `malloc`. It probably contains pointers to other allocations, and if you just `free` it, you'll lose the ability to free those allocations and have bad memory leaks.
2. The pointer returned by the library may not be to the beginning of the `malloc`-obtained object, but instead to some point inside it. In this case, passing it to `free` invokes undefined behavior, and may seem to work, or crash, or corrupt memory so that you only see the effects of corruption much later.
3. The library might keep an internal index of the objects it has allocated (`stdio` in the standard library would be a great example of this) in which case if you `free` the object behind its back, it will later access freed memory and invoke undefined behavior.

The most important rule of using `free` is that you must **never** pass any pointer to `free` unless that pointer was obtained by (or "as if by") `malloc`. Some libraries may document that they return a pointer obtained by `malloc`, and that you are supposed to pass it to `free` when you no longer need it, but unless you see this contract in writing, never pass pointers obtained by library functions to `free`.

As for `libxml2`, here is the manual:

http://xmlsoft.org/html/

It should contain information on how to free objects allocated by libxml2.

Comment: By ...Free I meant "..." will be replaced by the corresponding obj type.  For example,
    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseMemory(...);
    xmlDocFree(doc);
If you look at the manual entry for xmlParseMemory, it says nothing about freeing the doc.

Comment: I can only guess that since the object "doc" is created, it must be freed, and that seems to work.  But there are cases, it is not easy to tell if an obj is created or referenced, and a ...Free will blow up somewhere along the way.

Comment: If you're talking about calling the library's `xmlDocFree` function and similar rather than `free`, I think you're doing the right thing, but it's hard to tell with some poorly-documented libraries...